# Is there an alternative to the Dukt Rest plugin for Craft 3?

Tags: plugins, cookies

I am using a combination of two Craft 2 plugins, Cookies and Rest to get the logged in status of a user. What is the recommended way of doing this in Craft 3?

```
{% set userReq =
  craft.rest.request
    .headers({
      Cookie: cookie
    })
    .url("https://api2.lumi.com/auth/current")
    .send()
%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Fetch plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/fetch) to make HTTP requests from a template in Craft 3 and there's a [Cookies](https://plugins.craftcms.com/cookies) plugin for reading and writing cookies via a template that should do what you want.